# Is there a way to capture packets of one specific Android App

Tags: android, pcap, packet-capture

I need a way to capture packets of a specific android app and want to save it as a pcap file. I've used *Shark for root* but can't target a specific app.

I've tried using *AFWall+* to block all traffic except the one of my specific app but i did get packets from different Apps. (So it probably captures tries.) Should this work and i'm doing something wrong?

The App *Packet Capture* can resolve Packets to Apps but has no option to save it as pcap.

Any Ideas? 
Thanks a lot

Comment: Haven't tried by myself but it seems have those features.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.co.taosoftware.android.packetcapture&hl=en

Comment: Perfect. I tested this app but i didn't realise it has a Pro version that does exactly what i need. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Use the open [android pcap library](https://www.kismetwireless.net/static/android-pcap/) by the Wireless Kismet. Since it is open you are able to customise it in ways you want.